# Is there an equivalent in Entity Framework for CASE WHEN SomeCol IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

Tags: t-sql, entity-framework-6, case-statement

The T-SQL statement is below, essentially I want to return a boolean computed field `xmlHasValue`

```
SELECT TOP 10
    hrd.pkID
    , etc=  "etc..."
    , xmlHasValue = CASE WHEN hdr.someVeryLongXml IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM MyLeftTable hdr
    inner JOIN MyRightTable lines ON hdr.pkID = lines.fkID
WHERE hdr.SomeField == 123
ORDER BY hdr.pkID DESC
```

How can I write this in EntityFramework (Full Fx, not dotnet-core), such that EF produces the `Case` statement as above?

My attempt:

```
 var query = from hdr in dbCtx.MyLeftTable
    join lines in dbCtx.MyRightTable on hdr.pkID equals lines.fkID
    where hdr.SomeField == 123
    orderby hdr.pkID descending
    select new  //select into anon C# obj
    {
        pkID = hdr.pkID,
        etc = "etc...",
        xmlHasValue = hdr.someVeryLongXml //<== ??? stuck here ???
    };

var anonObjList = query.AsNoTracking()
        .Take(10)
        .ToList(); //exec qry on the SERVER, and fill the anon object.
```

Comment: use C# conditional operator (`? : `)

Comment: Ok, i will try that and come back here to accept your answer if you write it as an answer.